# The client driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-express

I'm developing an asp.net web application and using SQL express database in my application so every time when start the visual studio and insert the data by writing query i got this error.

> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The client driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all attempts failed.  Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase the number of recovery attempts

any help will be greatly appreciated thanks!

Comment: I just had this issue inside of SSMS and I hit debug and then it was connected again.

Comment: yes, thanks, I did the same and worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Same thing happened to me when using SSMS 2019, I just simply reconnect to the database by disconnecting and connecting again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34910117)